# Can't find toga.style python error message

Tags: python, beeware

hi i'm trying to create a application with python, so i'm using the beeware, i installed toga with `pip3 install toga` and `pip3 install beeware`

when i try to run a test script it gives me this error messages:

Import "toga.style" could not be resolved

Import "toga.style.pack" could not be resolved

this is the test code that i'm running:

```
        import toga
    from toga.style import Pack
    from toga.style.pack import COLUMN, ROW
    
    class SimpleCalculator(toga.App):
        def startup(self):
            main_box = toga.Box()
            self.main_window = toga.MainWindow(title=self.formal_name)
            self.main_window.content = main_box
            self.main_window.show()
    
    def main():
        return SimpleCalculator()
```

Comment: Make sure that the you are installing dependencies with the same Python interpreter used to run the code -- https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Answer (score 1):

The documentation on the Toga website is for version 0.3.0, which is currently in a pre-release state. You can upgrade as follows:

```
pip3 install --pre --upgrade toga
```

Comment: The issue might be that `pip3` does not correspond to the Python interpreter used to run the code, which would lead to the Python interpreter not being able to import the packages.

Comment: @sinoroc: If that was the problem, then it would have failed on the first line: `import toga`.